# Highlander: the Immortal and PCGen

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pcgen

Anyone know how i can add the Highlander Immortal sourcebook to PCGen for D&D 3.5? I am unsure if I should make this a template, since these effects are all acquired. If so, I am clueless about how to do all of this work. The PCGen help video does not cover this at all.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site! I'm hoping that we could get some more information from you about your problem, to improve our ability to help you. Firstly, is this 'Highlander Immortal sourcebook' you mention available in any place on the Internet? Does it have an ISBN entry, or a full proper title that can be searched? Who's the publisher? Any other identifying information will do us a world of good in getting to help you. Secondly, which specific parts of the material seem especially difficult to convert, in a way that the help doesn't cover?